# how to make R's philentropy::distance function completely quiet?

Tags: r

How can I make `philentropy::distance(...)` not display any text to the console? For example, 
    `distance(rbind((1:3),(4:6)), method="avg")`
displays "Metric: 'avg'; comparing: 2 vectors. avg 6" to the console. How do I make it not display anything?

For example, the `sink()` function only hides "avg 6":

```
    sink(tempfile(), append=FALSE, split=FALSE)
    distance(rbind((1:3),(4:6)), method="avg")
    sink()
```

The `invisible()` function also does not work for me:

```
    invisible(distance(rbind((1:3),(4:6)), method="avg"))
```

Here is some version information:

```
    platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
    arch           x86_64
    os             mingw32
    system         x86_64, mingw32
    status
    major          3
    minor          5.3
    year           2019
    month          03
    day            11
    svn rev        76217
    language       R
    version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
```

Comment: Try `suppressMessages(.)`

Comment: Thanks! `invisible(suppressMessages(distance(rbind((1:3),(4:6)), method="avg")))` and `suppressMessages(invisible(distance(rbind((1:3),(4:6)), method="avg")))` both hide the output

Comment: Search to see if it's a duplicate; if not write your own answer, why not?